# Why can't gnutls contact this site?

Tags: certificates

Why can't `gnutls` contact the site in question, even though wget gets the page just fine?

```
$ gnutls-cli https://site.com/login.php --insecure --print-cert < /dev/null > cert
WARNING: gnome-keyring:: couldn't connect to: /run/user/dotancohen/keyring-Ekufyf/pkcs11: No such file or directory
Cannot resolve https://site.com/login.php:443: Name or service not known
$ wget https://site.com/login.php
--2013-01-23 19:07:57--  https://site.com/login.php
Resolving site.com (site.com)... 72.1.2.3
Connecting to site.com (site.com)|72.1.2.3|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 6581 (6.4K) [text/html]
Saving to: `login.php'

100%[=============================================>] 6,581       --.-K/s   in 0s

2013-01-23 19:07:58 (47.8 MB/s) - `login.php' saved [6581/6581]

$
```

Comment: Is this true for any and all sites or just some?  What is the gnutls version (`gnutl-cli -v`)?

Comment: `gnutls-cli` expects a hostname (with -p for the port), not a URL

Comment: Thank you Stephane. How does it handle virtual hosts, then, i.e. when multiple sites are hosted on the same server by the same apache instance, on the same IP and port?

Comment: @dotancohen: 1) You must understand that `gnutls-cli` is only a TLS (SSL) client – it doesn't care at all about higher-level protocols such as HTTP. 2) However, at TLS level, if you give `gnutls-cli` a hostname, it sends that hostname to the server, the same way as browsers do – and that's sufficient for the server to pick the right certificate.

Comment: @dotancohen: (The protocol extension for this is "Server Name Indication". It's fairly new, however, and many older SSL servers simply put all vhost names into a single certificate, or only host one site per IP address.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Stephane Chazelas noted in their comment, the problem is that you're giving an URL instead of a hostname. `gnutls-cli` is only a SSL/TLS client and does not know anything about URIs or higher-level protocols such as HTTP; it expects to be given only a hostname (or IP address) to connect to.